# Scalar Flow Across a Small Area Element

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vectors, tensor-calculus

I've just started reading the text "Vectors, Tensors, and the Basic Equations of Fluid Mechanics" by Rutherford Aris and I came across the following problem.

If $\rho$ is any scalar property per unit volume of a fluid in motion, show how to define a flux vector $\vec{f}$ such that $f_i$ is the rate of flow of $\rho$ per unit area across a small element perpendicular to the axis $0i$.

My instincts tell me it will be related to the velocity of the fluid in motion. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried some form of dimensional analysis?

Comment: @nluigi $\vec{f}=\rho\vec{v}$?

Comment: Maybe :), does that make sense to you physically?

Comment: @nluigi It seems to make sense; the flux vector will be flowing in the same direction as the velocity of the fluid, and it also relates the density of the fluid with the flux vector.

Comment: You need to use the component of the velocity in the 0i direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider a one-dimensional control volume, $V=DHdx$ where $dx$, $D$ and $H$ are the length, depth and height of the control volume respectively.

The change of a scalar quantity per volume $\rho$ in the control volume by purely convective transport is then:
$$\frac{\partial(\rho V)}{\partial t} = \rho v DH|_x - \rho v DH|_{x+dx}$$

We identify $F=\rho v DH$ to be the total amount of the scalar quantity flowing in and out of the system.

Using the definition of the gradient:
$$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}DHdx = -\frac{\partial(\rho v)}{\partial x} DHdx$$

and simplifying:
$$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} = -\frac{\partial(\rho v)}{\partial x}$$

We can identify $f=\rho v$ as the total amount of the scalar quantity **per unit area** flowing in and out of the system.

This analysis is easily extended to multiple dimensions using vector analysis.

Comment: What does the quantity $B$ represent? Or was that a typo

Comment: Very nicely done by the way; this is a bit beyond my skill level at the moment, but hopefully with some practice I'll be able to derive these kinds of results.

Comment: Also, what does the subscript in the first align environment represent?

Comment: @AlexS - it was a typo. The control volume extends from position $x$ to $x+dx$, to relate the ingoing and outgoing fluxes to the change in the controle volume you need to evaluate the fluxes at the faces of the control volume, i.e. at $x$ and $x+dx$.

Answer (score 0):

I am reading the same book as well. Here is my attempt at a solution. Please let me know if I am thinking about this correctly because I am not sure it is correct, but hopefully on the correct tract.

From Aris:
Definition of a Vector: A cartesian vector $\textbf{a}$ in 3 dimensions is a quantity with 3 components $a_1,a_2,a_3$, in the frame of reference $O123$, which, under rotation of the coordinate frame $O\bar{1}\bar{2}\bar{3}$, become components $\bar{a_1},\bar{a_2},\bar{a_3}$, where $\bar{a_j} = l_{ij}a_i$.

Here, Aris' notation of the direction cosine is: $l_{ij} = cos(\alpha_i)$

I drew out the three coordiante directions $(O_i : O1,O2, O3)$ and showed myself that it doesn't matter which coordinate direction we take. $\rho$ will always flow through a 'per unit area' through a cubic element.

From the problem statement:
$\rho$ is a scalar going in and out of the volume
$f_i$ is the rate of flow of the scalar ($\rho$) per unit area perpendicular to axis $O_i$
$n_i$ are the unit vectors (directions) in which the flow acts
$\bar{n_j} = l_{ij}n_i$
$\textbf{f}$ : flux

$\textbf{f} = \rho f_in_i$ = $\rho f_1n_1 + \rho f_2n_2 + \rho f_2n_2$

This dimensionally satisfies flux. Now lets see if we rotate this to a new coordinate axis, if the definition is satisfied.
$O123$ to $O\bar{1}\bar{2}\bar{3}$, $\bar{n_j} = l_{ij}n_i$

$\bar{\textbf{f}_j}$ = $\rho f_i\bar{n_j}$ = $\rho f_il_{ij}n_i$ = $l_{ij}(\rho f_in_i)$

Therefore: $\bar{\textbf{f}_j}$ = $l_{ij}\textbf{f}$ and satisfies rotation and our definition of a vector: $\bar{a_j} = l_{ij}a_i$.